# Reading data from a python socket received from multiple clients

Tags: python, sockets, distributed-system

I am writing a python program (master.py) to read the data received from 2 separate clients. This is the code example:

master.py:

```
data_agg = ''
HOST = '172.31.31.207'
PORT = 50008
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind((HOST, PORT))
s.listen(2)
conn, addr = s.accept()
print 'Connected by', addr
while 1:
    data = conn.recv(65535)
    data_agg += data
    if not data: break

data_arr = json.loads(data_agg.decode('utf-8'))
data_arr = sorted(data_arr)
print "Sorted attay: \n"
print data_arr
```

Two clients have the following code:

```
HOST = '172.31.31.207'
PORT = 50008
s0 = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s0.connect((HOST, PORT))
s0.send(sorted_data_string)
s0.close()
```

However i only receive data from a single client. What would be a proper way to read the data from a socket arriving from multiple receivers?

Comment: If you want your server th handle multiple clients , you should put `accept()` in a loop and add new clients to a list .  Then you can read - write to each of those sockets

Answer (score -1):

If you want your server th handle multiple clients, you can put `accept()` in a loop and add new clients to a list of connected clients. Then you can read - write to each of those clients.

```
HOST = '172.31.31.207'
PORT = 50008
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind((HOST, PORT))
s.listen(2)
clients = []
while True:
    conn, addr = s.accept()
    clients += [{'conn':conn, 'addr':addr}]
    print 'Connected by', addr
    data_agg = ''
    while True:
        data = conn.recv(65535)
        if not data: 
            break
        data_agg += data
    data_arr = sorted(json.loads(data_agg.decode('utf-8')))
    print "Sorted attay: \n"
    print data_arr 
    conn.close()
s.close()
```

You could improve the above code by using `thread`,  so that you can handle multiple clients at the same time.  You can do this by defining a `handle_client` function, and run it on a new thread.

```
while True: 
    conn, addr = s.accept()
    print 'Connected by', addr
    start_new_thread(handle_client, (conn,))
```

Comment: `conn.recv()` returns bytes instead of str, so you cannot concatenate `data` to `data_agg` because one is bytes and the other is str.

Comment: @oeter This is clearly Python2 code (notice the missing parentheses in `print` statements). Python2 `''` are equivalent to Python3 `b''`, and Python3 `''` are Python2's `u''`. Thanks for your remark, but this code is obviously not Python3 compatible, for many reasons